# Conditional joins in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to query for a dataset in SQL Server and have one of the return columns based on either one of two subqueries.  The control of which subquery is from a value of another column in the query.  Some basic pseudo query language of what I'm trying to do:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
if col3 = 1
     (select count(*) from table2 where table2.col1 = table1.col1) as count1
else
     (select count(*) from table3 where table3.col1 = table1.col1) as count1
from table1
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
    CASE WHEN col3 = 1 THEN
        (SELECT count(*) 
        FROM table2 
         WHERE table2.col1 = table1.col1)
    ELSE
        (SELECT count(*)
        FROM table3 
        WHERE table3.col1 = table1.col1)
    END  AS count1
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable and `SELECT` column `col3` into it.

Or you could do a `CASE...WHEN` block.